# Почему не работает android:theme для TextInputLayout в android 4.4?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity

Почему-то не работает android:theme для TextInputLayout в версии android 4.4.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_input_project_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/Name_project"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTextInputAddContactProject">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/name_project_create"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                        android:text="sdsd"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/color_gray_text"
                        app:backgroundTint="@color/color_gray_text"
                        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_gray_text"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false" />
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Вот стиль, который использую

```
<style name="EditTextInputAddContactProject">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ff0400</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#00ff04</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#0055ff</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ff0400</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#ffea00</item>
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">#00ff04</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#00ff04</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#00ff04</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">#ff0400</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">#ff0400</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#ff0400</item>
</style>
```

Уточнение:

Есть глобальный стиль, который подключается в манифесте и если разметку layout(в котором проблема, описанная выше) использовать в activity, то проблема остаётся, а если этот же layout использовать в фрагменте, то проблемы нет.

Стиль:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">#277dd3</item>
</style>
```

Манифест:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:name=".utils.App"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"> <!-- Глобальный стиль-->
```

В чём проблема и как устранить?

Для проверки использую эмулятор.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `android:theme` использовать `style` в разметке

Comment: Не уверен, но можно попробовать `app:theme`.

Comment: Темы и стили это такая тема (извините за каламбур), что всегда все приходится делать по наитию, так что я лично пас